# Firebird Switch from "Similar to" to "Like"

Tags: sql, firebird, sql-like

I have created a domain using the "Similar to" function under firebird 2.5, but now I have to downgrade my database to Firebird 2.1, and it seems impossible beacause of that function.
I want to find the way to express my domain with the "Like" function so that it runs in Firebird 2.1. Here is my domain code :

```
CREATE DOMAIN CODET
 AS varchar(16)
 NOT NULL
 CHECK (char_length(value)=16
 and
 value SIMILAR TO 
  '[G]{1}[C,M,E]{1} [1-6]{1} [E]{1}[P,S,L]{1} 
  [A-E]{1} [0-9]{1}[0-9]{1} [0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}'
  and substring(value from 14 for 3)>'000')
 COLLATE NONE;
```

Comment: Could that SIMILAR TO pattern be compacted and corrected to: `'G[CME] [1-6] E[PSL] [A-E] [0-9]{2} [0-9]{3}'` ?  In SQL regexes, a character class consisting of a single character is equivalent to that single character, so `[G]` is equivalently `G`.  A quantifier of exactly one (`{1}`) after a regular primary is the same as just that primary, so `G{1}` is equivalently `G`.  A comma inside a character class matches a comma, so `[C,M,E]` matches a `,` or `C` or `M` or `E` — but the repetition of the comma suggests it is (incorrectly) intended to delimit a series.

Comment: @pilcrow I think the regex pattern was auto-generated by some tool, so manual compacting would make not lot of sense :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to "translate" it term by term, ie

- the first one is `[G]{1}` which means that value must start with `G` so this becomes `value STARTING WITH 'G'`
- `[C,M,E]{1}` - second character must be either C, M or E which is `(value like '_C%')or(value like '_M%')or(value like '_E%')`
- `[1-6]{1}` - fourth character must be number between 1 and 6, including. So `SUBSTRING(value FROM 4 FOR 1) BETWEEN '1' AND '6'`

and so on. And then combine them into one:

```
...
CHECK ( char_length(value)=16
   and value STARTING WITH 'G'
   and( (value like '_C%')or(value like '_M%')or(value like '_E%') )
   and SUBSTRING(value FROM 4 FOR 1) BETWEEN '1' AND '6'
   ...
)
```

As your string is fixed length and spaces in it are in fixed position you can check for them in single term like so

```
value like '__ _ __ _ __ ___'
```

ie all non-space positions are marked with `_` and space positions contain space character.

Alternatively you could use some UDF which implements `similar to` like operation.

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer is really helpful, but what about the blanck between the carracters ex: GC 2 EP A 22 200

Comment: One option is to extract that position as a substring and compare it against string, ie `SUBSTRING(value FROM 3 FOR 1) = ' '` (note that there is a space betveen quotes). Sometimes it is possible to include it into previous or next term, ie it seems that there must be a space in third position, so it can be included into previous term: `value like '_C %' or value like '_M %'...`.

Comment: Actually, you can check for spaces in single term, see the addition in my answer.